# Keeping code tidy on windows forms app with tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, coding-style

I'm currently developing an Windows Forms application in C# which will make use of tabs for the GUI. The problem I'm facing though is that the code is becoming untidy.
The reason is that the code for GUI components (such as button clicks) resides on the main form code.
So I'm looking for a way to still handle all the GUI interactions the same way but separate the code in a logical way (e.g. different files). Like having button1_click() reside in another file but work the same way as before.
Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like an MVVM approach here would both keep your code tidier and be more testable (each tab being its own "viewmodel"), leading to a more maintainable product.

Comment: @Mick MVVM is difficult with Windows Forms - typically, with WinForms, you'd do MVP, but yes, this can help tremendously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place each "Tab" into its own `UserControl`, and handle the events there instead of all within the main form.

As tabs typically each represent something "distinct", this is often fairly simple to implement, and helps clean up your code.

Comment: So for, say 8 tabs, I'll need to create 8 different UserControl s right?